# Wxpython driven by an external event

Tags: python, events, wxpython

I am learning python and wxpython and I wanted to know whether it is possible to have an external event, for instance, a new email, that could drive a change, for instance, split the main frame into two...

If so what would be the best way to do it.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there really isn't. You would need to monitor the email server using your wxPython program. Personally, I would use a thread that would check for new messages every few minutes. When a new message is found, it would use one of wxPython's thread-safe methods (`wx.CallAfter`, `wx.PostEvent`) to update the user interface.